# Debugging a personal TLS client implementation's ClientHello

Tags: tls, openssl

I wanted to implement [RFC 8446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446) to learn more about TLS. I've worked some with text based protocols like HTTP and SMTP. TLS is my first binary encoding to attempt implementing sections of.

I'm sending a *very* malformed ClientHello to `google.com:443`:

```
let client_hello: Vec<u8> = [3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I found [*The Illustrated TLS1.3 Connection: Every Byte Explained*](https://tls13.xargs.org/#client-hello/annotated) which should help a lot in correcting my message, but I'm having a very hard time figuring out why `google.com:443` responds to me, and what the response is:

```
let google_response: Vec<u8> = [21, 3, 1, 0, 2, 2, 10]
```

I think it might be an [alert](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-6)? If I just take the right most bytes `[2,10]` then it's an `unexpected_message`, but this doesn't explain the rest of the bits which are consistently returned.

What is this message? Is there a better way to debug SSL Client implementations? Something with openssl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data exchanged on a TLS connection is a series of records. [RFC 8446 §5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-5) describes the record protocol. The format of a record is:

- [1 byte] record content type;
- [2 bytes] protocol version, always 0x0303 for TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 (don't worry about exceptions for now);
- [2 bytes] length *N* of the following data (big-endian a.k.a. network-endian; all multi-byte integers are encoded in big-endian order unless otherwise specified);
- [*N* bytes] data, depending on the record content type.

What you send is a record of invalid type and version with a 0-byte payload, followed by more garbage. Google's response is a record with type=21 (alert), protocol version [3,1] meaning TLS 1.0 (presumably the oldest version the server supports, since you didn't give any indication of supporting a more recent version), and 2 bytes of content [2, 10]. Decoding this alert ([RFC 8446 §7.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2)), it's level 2 “fatal” and description 10 “unexpected message”.

Start by constructing valid records, before worrying about the contents of those records. TLS distinguishes *records* and *messages*, and allows messages to span multiple records, but don't worry about that for now: treat a record as one message, either a handshake message or a fragment of application data. TLS is a stream protocol so you can break application data into messages however you like.

For debugging, use a local server with debugging facilities rather than a remote server that you don't control. For example:

```
openssl s_server -debug -trace -www -accept 4433 -psk_identity whoiam -psk 73776f726466697368
```

or

```
openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -key mykey.pem -out mycert.crt -days 360
openssl s_server -debug -trace -www -accept 4433 -cert mycert.crt -key mykey.pem
```

Wireshark is also useful to see what you're sending or trying to parse.

Comment: I think the most helpful part was just you picking apart the message bytes. I wasn't very confident if it were big endian, little endian, or even which way those formats flow :). I probably needed to read the spec more and organize that information better.